# How to remove the space for column on Bootstrap 4 Grid Layout?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, html, google-web-designer

I am working on removing the space between Front End Developer and About Me modal. It doesn't seem to to work when I used classes such as no gutter and removing the paddings.

[Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9huvd.png)

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
<header>
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
      <img class="title-logo" src="./resources/images/logo.jpeg">
    </div>
    <div class="title-super col-md-4 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 text-uppercase text-right">
      <h1>Terence Fan</h1>
      <h4>Front-End Developer</h4>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark button-style" data-toggle='modal' data-target="#AboutMe">About Me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

I have the full Github source code [here](https://github.com/tfan1210/Portfolio)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this code to your CSS.

```
.title-super .btn {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works well! Any chance on how I can make the <hr> line right under the button?

Comment: You can try negative `margin-top` value to the `hr`. Try `header hr { margin-top: -20px; }`

Comment: And yes, ticking my answer as right one would be good idea :)

Comment: Or use the class `align-top` for the same thing without CSS.

Answer (score 0):

set `vertical-align: top` to `button-style`

```
.button-style {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gn3koo0w/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.align-top` [bootstrap css class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/vertical-align/) for vertical align element.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark button-style align-top" data-toggle='modal' data-target="#AboutMe">About Me</button>
```